# Connecting to Aerospike host via SSL using the JDBC driver defaults to 3000 port

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver, aerospike, datagrip

I am trying to connect to an aerospike host which requires SSL. Connecting via the aql command works fine. However connecting to the same using the JDBC driver fails.

Running the following command is able to successfully connect to aerospike

```
aql -h test-host.co.in:tls1:4333 --tls-enable --tls-cafile ~/certificates/aerospike-server-ca.pem
```

However when I try to connect using a JDBC connection string using the aerospike JDBC driver it fails the connect.
This is the jdbc connection string I used

```
jdbc:aerospike:ssl://test-host.co.in:4333?enableTLS=true&trustStorePath=~/certificates/aerospike-server-ca.pem
```

It gives an error that it failed to connect to ssl 3000. Is there something wrong in my JDBC string? I tried using this via Datagrip & DBeaver and faced the same error at both softwares. Why is this even defaulting to 3000 port when 4333 port is explicitly specified?

```
 Failed to connect to [1] host(s): ssl 3000
```

Comment: In DataGrip, try specifying `jdbc:aerospike:test-host.co.in:4333` as the JDBC string, then switch to the SSH/SSL tab, enable 'Use SSL' and provide your CA file there, then switch to the Advanced tab and add the `enableTLS=true` flag there if needed (although I'm not sure it is supported, see https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc/blob/main/docs/params.md).

Comment: I tried changing it as per your suggestion. But now it gives a slightly different error -
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Connection: Error java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there might be a few things wrong with your configuration. Judging by your AQL line it looks like your certificate has a name of "tls1" so you need to pass this to the JDBC driver with `&tlsName=tls1`. The `trustStorePath` you have isn't valid, I believe the parameter you're looking for is `tlsTruststorePath`. You can see a full list of the valid values at [AerospikeTLSPolicyConfig](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/aerospike/jdbc/tls/AerospikeTLSPolicyConfig.java).

However, I also believe that the configuration expects a standard Java truststore and not a .pem certificate. You should be able to convert your PEM file to a truststore using

```
keytool -import -alias serverkey -file aerospike-server-ca.pem -keystore truststore
```

You will then need to pass the password of the truststore you created using `&tlsTruststorePassword=<password>` where `<password>` is the password you selected when creating the truststore above.

So I would look at using a JDBC connect string similar to:

```
jdbc:aerospike://test-host.co.in:4333?enableTLS=true&tlsTruststorePath=/home/myuser/certificates/truststore&tlsTruststorePassword=<password>&tlsName=tls1
```

You will need to change `myuser` to your user name. Or make sure you put in the correct path to the truststore you created. "~" is an abstraction provided by the shell and Java does not recognise it, so a fully qualified path to your truststore is your best bet.

Note: based on your AQL line, I'm assuming you are NOT doin mTLS and therefore do not need provide client certs to the server.